# Odoo/OpenERP failed mail handling

Tags: python, odoo, cron-task, odoo-8

I have a question regarding odoo/openerp mail handling for typical situation.
Here is the scenario:-
I am using some odoo and performed any transaction that would trigger an email to my client, now for consideration I didn't have internet connected at that moment will odoo handle that on later stage like if the system will look for emails that got failed due to any reason and retry the same.

I tried to make a deeper drive for the same in Automation Panel I was able to see **scheduled action** I was able to see **Email Queue Manager** I did all the settings it had. Now the issue is I wanna know what odoo is using in back-end like Crontab or any other kind of scheduler that will let you me know if the schedules have been qued and wait for the same to hit the script and process the Que.

Any one who know odoo will be able to answer the question. If you are not getting my question and are aware of odoo. 
Please let me know. I will do my best to explain the situation.

Thanks and Regards

Chand Prakash

Comment: You can check all the methods related with Cron in the `ir.cron` model (`ir_cron.py` file). You have the `_acquire_job` method that is in charge of getting and processing all the jobs from the database (`ir_cron` table). That function is ran periodically each minute. Is that what you're looking for? What would you like to do exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the response @ChesuCR. But what I am looking for is the how the periodic system is setup like it can be using cronjob it can be using any other software that trigerrs things in a period of some duration.
Also I want all the failed mails that were not sent during the duration when SMTP was an issue to be resent when the machine connects to internet.